# Deploy node.js application to elastic beanstalk (using express)

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, express

I've been having issues deploying my app to elastic beanstalk all day today. I have following project structure (single page app built with react)

```
dist/
  index.html
  bundle.js
package.json
app.js
```

I zip it and upload to elastic beanstalk running node.js

here is **app.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/dist'));

app.get('/*', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/dist/index.html');
});

app.listen(8080, function() {
  console.log('Listening on port: ' + 8080);
});
```

Locally, it all wоrks fine, but aws thrоws warnings.

Comment: @davka `Application update failed at 2016-02-05T16:50:37Z with exit status 1 and error: Hook /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/50npm.sh failed.` And this command seems to be an issue `node-pre-gyp` (aws runs it, I have no idea what it it is, but after it is run I get tons of errors prefixed as `gyp ERR!`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who comes across similar issue, it turned out that it was related to some of the dependencies I used, so it could be worth downgrading them, and not use `^ version`.

You will be able to find further info on this via logs that eb produces.